# ocaml interpreter

Tags: ocaml, interpreter

Can someone give me some help building an ocaml interpreter for the language with the syntax:

```
Prog ::= Def* Expr
Def ::= id id* = Expr
Expr ::= int | id | Expr '+' Expr | Expr '*' Expr | id Expr* | if Expr then Expr else Expr
```

so far i did this:

```
type expr = I of int
| Id of string
| Add of expr * expr
| Multiply of expr * expr
| If of  expr * expr * expr

let rec evaluate = function
| I n -> n 
| Add(e1,e2) -> evaluate e1 + evaluate e2
| Multiply(e1,e2) -> evaluate e1 * evaluate e2
| If(a,b,c) -> if evaluate a<>0 then evaluate b else evaluate c
```

Is this any good ?

Answer (score 6):

In your grammar a single id can either be matched by the production `Expr ::= id` or `Expr ::= id Expr*`. In other words there's no way to distinguish between a nullary function application (assuming the `id Expr*` production is supposed to match function applications) and variables. Maybe you meant `id Expr+` instead (disallowing nullary function applications).

Your existing code looks fine, but it's incomplete:

Your `expr` type is missing a constructor for the `id Expr*` production of the grammar, i.e. you're missing a constructor that represents function applications. You should add one and then add a case for it to the `evaluate` function as well.

In your `evaluate` function you're missing a case for the `Id` constructor. That case should lookup the value of the given identifier in a mapping from identifiers to values (ints). To that end your `evaluate` function should take such a mapping as an additional argument. It should also take another mapping from identifiers to functions, which you can then use to loop up function names in the case for function applications.

Speaking of those mappings, you currently don't have any code to represent or process definitions. You should come up with a type to represent a definition and another to represent functions. The latter type should contain the name of the function parameters and the body as an `expr`.

Then you should write a function that takes a list of definitions and creates the mappings for variables and functions. For each variable definition it should evaluate the expression on the right and add the resulting values to your variable mapping. For each function definition, you should add a value of your function type to the function mapping. After processing the definitions, you should evaluate the final expression by calling your `evaluate` function with that expression and the two mappings you created as arguments.

Finally you don't have any code for actually parsing the program, but I think that might be intentional.

Comment: Can you please show me an example of a code to represent the process of definitions? I do not need code for parsing, and i did not wrote the Id constructor becouse i didn't know how, if you can show me please.

Comment: @Spreadzz The type would just be something like `type def = Def of string * string list * expr` or, if you want to distinguish between variable and function definitions, `type def = VarDef of string * expression | FunDef of string * string list * expression`.

Comment: Can you show me the type def of Add and Multiply in my interpretor so i can fully understant ?

Comment: @Spreadzz What do you mean by "the type def of Add and Multiply"? The type called `def` that I defined in my earlier comment has nothing to do with the `Add` and `Multiply` constructors of the `exp` type.

Comment: Then i really messed it up in understanding, i tought the type def is related. I hate oCaml pfu :) It's a school project. Then the type def you defined is for my interpreter Def ::= id id* = Expr  ?  Sorry for the stupid question but i am new to ocaml, and ml languages

Comment: @Spreadzz The type `def` is supposed to represent definitions. A function definition consists of the function's name, a list of the function's parameters' names and the body of the function (as an `expr`). The body of the function can of course contain Addition or Multiplication, but that really doesn't matter because all you need to do is to store the body together with the function's name and parameter list when the `def` is processed and then retrieve that information when the function is called. It doesn't matter what kind of expression the body is.